# Visual Development Tools

Tags: c#

The company I work for is writing software for financial organizations and this often involves doing some complex calculations. Right now, a functional designer will just write down the calculation and then someone more technical (me) has to translate this to code.

However, I realize that this should probably be done in an easier way. Isn't there already some tool in which you can just design your functions and calculations in an easy-to-understand visual way, which would compile to a .NET assembly that can be used within my projects? That way, the functional designer just has to "draw" the formula in this tool, generate the code/assembly and pass that on to me.

(I must say, for this purpose we're already some graphical design tool but it's too limited for the more complex calculations.)
[These calculations are related to loans, mortgages and insurances, often doing complex calculations to predict the profitability of a certain product compared to others.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used tools that try to do formulae via designers; they are usually terrible.

Perhaps a better idea is to use a user-friendly syntax for the formula? I've seen this done with Python in the past (IronPython would be a good embedded language in .NET). Or just parse a string in an expected syntax yourself? (not hugely complicated)

Comment: Problem is that the functional designer has no technical background and no programming experience. Within a visual environment it should be easier for him to design the calculations. Which is why a visual environment has my preference.

Comment: The point is that the language isn't about **programming** - it is about the **maths**. Presumably they could do the formula in Excel? Think along those terms...

Comment: Actually, I use my code generator below to convert a .xlsx to .cs through the OpenXML Format SDK 2.0: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en

Comment: Yep. Right now those formula's are done in Excel. (And sometimes given to me in Excel format.)

Comment: (And those Excel sheet/formulas need to be translated to code again.)

Comment: My point is that if a user can express it in Excel, they can express it in a related DSL, or in something like Python.

Answer (score 1):

Build a Domain Specific Language package for Visual Studio. It's a well-documented and very common task. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126235.aspx

Comment: Our thoughts exactly. Which is why we've developed some in-house DSL project to do this. Unfortunately, it's developed by another team and it's too limited.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tool for generating your own DSL.  10 pages to orbit,
and a tutorial too boot:

http://www.bayfronttechnologies.com/mc_tutorial.html

Comment: Two problems: 1) We already created a DSL but it lacks too much functionality at this moment. And 2) We need a short-term solution because the team that created our DSL is falling apart because of the lack of functionality that it needed.

Comment: @Alex: if you are serious, you can implement this tool in a day or two, and then implement another DSL with the functionality you want in about a week.  I did the first part as an undergraduate in 1970 by myself, and used this tool for this purpose many times.

Answer (score 0):

I have a FileGenerators project as part of my solution. It allows me to use a [single file generators as custom tools](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/customtoolsexp.aspx) for special code generation tasks. It's set up using attributes to save me a lot of time configuring Visual Studio to use them.

Here is a copy of the source I'm using for the special project. I stripped it a bit but it should be very close. *Make sure you set your project to register for COM interop upon build.* [Dons flamesuit for code quality since this is an internal tool that I threw together because I just needed something to work for a test case.]
http://www.280z28.org/downloads/Pimp.FileGenerators.7z

Edit: I use this in one case for converting an Excel .xlsx file to C# code with the help of the [Open XML Format SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en)

Comment: If only we used MS Office 2007... We're stuck at version 2003, and .xlsx isn't supported.

Comment: Then use the Excel interop API maybe? This solution works for any combination of input/output formats and integrates cleanly into your solution.

Comment: Using Excel would also fail for another reason. The resulting project is part of a client application that's distributed to about 3000 licensees. It would mean that I have to include the Excel sheet too and hope they've all have Excel installed. Furthermore, there's a performance issue. It's not unusual for a calculation to be repeated for every product/company combination in the product, which would be around 5000 records. This needs to be done fast.

Comment: You write a program as part of your build that reads a spreadsheet and builds *code* for you from it that runs. All you're doing is taking the step you do manually and automating it.